# Get audio data from twilio <gather> using twilio functions

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I need to extract the audio file from a gathered speech of an in-progress call in twilio instead of the text result of the speech which is accessible using *event.SpeechResult()* function. I had tried checking out the API and even logging the event but wasn't able to get the required info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio data is not present in `<Gather>` API. It only gives the transcribed speech result. To get the audio data, `<Record>` should be used in the similar manner.

Comment: you mean Record verb should be used?